# How to achieve a page controlling system in NodeJS & ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I am totally new to node- and expressJS.
I have been trying to setup a website using `node` and `expressjs`. Making the server was obviously not rocket science so that was done
but currently I am trying to understand how a page controller can be achieved as I would do in `PHP`.

(in PHP) usually, I create a folder which contains all the pages that are supposed to be displayed inside the main container
when that specific page is requested by `/?page=` parameter two different variables are changed, `title` and `page`.

```
<?php
    require('connect.php');

    $pages = array(
        "home" => array("title" => "Home", "fontIcon" => "fas fa-home"),
        "accounts" => array("title" => "Accounts", "fontIcon" => "fas fa-key"),
        "players" => array("title" => "Players", "fontIcon" => "fas fa-users"),
        "posts" => array("title" => "Posts", "fontIcon" => "fas fa-newspaper"),
        "polls" => array("title" => "Polls", "fontIcon" => "fas fa-poll"),
        "shop" => array("title" => "Shop Items", "fontIcon" => "fas fa-shopping-cart"),
        "bans" => array("title" => "Banishments", "fontIcon" => "fas fa-user-slash")
    );

    // Check if (/?p=) parameter is set
    if(!isset($_REQUEST['p'])){
        $page = "home";
        $title = $pages["home"];
    } else {

        // See if requested page exists
        if(array_key_exists($_REQUEST['p'], $pages)){

            // iterate over pages array
            foreach ($pages as $p => $t) {

                // set page and title
                if($_REQUEST['p'] === $p){
                    $page = $p;
                    $title = $t;
                }
            }

        // use default page & title if requested page doesnt exist in array
        } else {
            $page = "home";
            $title = $pages["home"];
        }
    }

    // set path for requested page
    $page = "pages/".$page.".php";

?>
```

However in expressJS tutorials I haven't been able to find such code to accomplish what I've described above.
Authors have only been showing simple examples such as the code below, which doesn't seem to be an efficient way of controlling pages.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    // ... bla bla
});

app.get('/contact', function(req, res){
    // ... bla bla
});

app.get('/about', function(req, res){
    // ... bla bla
});
```

So basically I am trying to achieve something like the following structure in node&expressJS:

A main page where page controller will be implemented and displayable pages will be stored in a different directory
where each page will be uniquely accessed by a url request.

```
_NodeExressAPP_
|
|__ pages/__page__.ejs
|
|__ backend/__page__.js
|
|__ views / index.ejs (main page)
|
|__ pageController.js
|
|_ server.js (include pageController)
```

It seems like express/node doesn't let me combine files as php would and therefore Im thinking that one is forced to create seperate, individual, html documents for each view... and this is what bothers me most. I don't want to create the whole html document all over again or copy paste it into a new file in order to have another view. I want it to combine the requested page into index.ejs (root file)

Answer (score 0):

What I understand, basically you are trying to setup a routing system in node and express. Express provides a very efficient routing system. Routes can be managed in multiple ways in express. I will be writing a small example, it may help you getting started. Further you may use an express generator which immediately builds a basic project for creator.

```
    //Server.js file
    const express = require('express');
    let app = express();

    // Define a separate file for your route 
    // Define a folder , the folder may contain files for various concerns 
    let router = require('./controller/location_routes');

    // The application have access to all the routes defined in locatin_routes.js file
    app.use(router);


    app.listen(3000,()=> {
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
    });


    // Location_routes.js file inside controller folder
    // Create a controller folder in root and add new file named (location_routes.js)
    const express = require('express');

    const router = express.Router();

    router.get('/location', (req, res ,next) => {

    console.log('I am Location route');
    res.send('Get locations');
    });


    router.post('/location', (req, res ,next) => {

    console.log('I am Add location route');
    res.send('Location Added');
   });

   module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Visit references 
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html      
            
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html